# How to Keep Nested <li> <a> tag active and visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, html-lists, submenu

I have this website http://firesafetyexpo.in/ (I am referring to the left side nested list menu).

When I click on the menu with sub-links (E.g "About Fire & Safety India" -> any link inside it), the page opens up but the "clicked" menu is not visible. I want to make the whole `<ul>` to be seen with sub-links (`<li>`).

here is the html code:

```
<li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Welcome</span></a></li>
<li class='has-sub'><a href=""><span>About Fire & Safety India</span></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="pdf/Fire-Safety-Layout.pdf" target="_blank"><span>Floor plan</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="media-partners.html"><span>Support and Media Partners</span></a></li>
    <li class='last'><a href="organisers.html"><span>About Organisers</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Here is the jquery code:

```
  ( function( $ ) {
      $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
      $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 
      var checkElement = $(this).next();
        if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
          $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
          checkElement.slideUp('normal');
        }
        if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
          $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
          checkElement.slideDown('normal');
        }
        if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;   
     }      
   });
   });
   } )( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on a menu the whole page refreshes making the HTML refresh as well. This way all the DOM operations that you have done with JavaScript are simply lost. No matter if you added a specific class or deleted an element.

One way to solve the problem is to make the whole application SPA (single-page application). But I don't believe writing the whole site again is worth it.

Probably the easiest thing you can do here is just getting the URL and getting the substring after your domain name. All your HTML elements should have the same ID as your routes. This way you can simply select the element with the same ID as your URL substring and add the class `active`.

**---Edit---**

Ok, first i will tell you something i saw while browsing your site. Most of the links in the navigation do nothing. Just delete them f you don't need them...

You can easily organize your html files in folders. For example you will have a main folder where all the .html files are stored. `index.html` is directly in it. Next to `index.html` create the folder `about` and putt all .html files that are called from the About tab in the navigation.

This way your URL will look something like `http://firesafetyexpo.in/about/media-partners.html`

Fix the `href` in the navigation (for example `href=about/media-partners.html`).

Add IDs to all the main tabs in your navigation. (`<li id="about" class='has-sub'><a href=""><span>About Fire & Safety India</span></a>` (you don't need the <span> here... it is up to you. you will get the same result with `<li id="about" class='has-sub'><a href="">About Fire & Safety India</a>`)).

**Finally** add this function to your JavaScript file.

```
$(function() {
    $('#cssmenu a#' + location.pathname.split("/")[1]).addClass('active');
});
```

I haven't tried this code. I really hope it works (:

Comment: Thanks. But i will need code to understand this as I am not a full fledge programmer. Can you share a bit of code so i can continue with the rest..

Comment: Edited my answer. I hope this is more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I tried your above solution, it does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I tried your above solution, it does not work.

Questions: 1. What is the use of `id="about"` (your above suggestion), 2. i tried removing / keeping the above JS code that i had pasted here and used your js code, it still doesn't work. 

Can u try if I share you the zip file of just the original menu? Here is the [link] (http://firesafetyexpo.in/Elegant-Accordin%20-Menu1.zip). 

My requirement: 
- the parent link of the sub-menu tab should also be clickable (a html page) + the sub-menus should be visible. 

If you try this i would be grateful to you. awaiting.Thanks.